# Summing an array of Objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, aggregate

I have an array of objects that are holding integer values.

```
$row = new-Object PSObject # create a new object to hold its data
$row | Add-Member -Name "sheet_number" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 1
$row | Add-Member -Name "frame_number" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 2     
$row | Add-Member -Name "sheet_height" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 1200         
$row | Add-Member -Name "frame_height" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 1200    
$row | Add-Member -Name "frame_width"  -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 3300 
$row | Add-Member -Name "orientation"  -MemberType NoteProperty -Value 0 
$frames += $row
```

this is in a for loop intended to iterate through several times. But the sheet_number property should only have a couple values. what I need is to sum up the values in frame_width where the sheet_number is the same.

Pseudo Code:

```
sheet_width = sum of frame_width where sheet number = 1
```

Comment: ...but if this is in a loop, wouldn't all the values be the same from what youve pasted in your post?

Comment: The example above was just a visual. I am using variables as values in the objects. they change for every iteration

Answer (score 4):

Use a combination of [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object), [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object), and [`Measure-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object):

```
$sum = (
 $frames | 
   Where-Object sheet_number -eq 1 |
     ForEach-Object frame_width |
       Measure-Object -Sum
).Sum
```

To do it for *all* sheet numbers, additionally use [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object):

```
$arrayOfSums =
 $frames | 
   Group-Object sheet_number |
     ForEach-Object {
       ($_.Group.frame_width | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
     }
```